# "Unexpected Token <" Meteor

Tags: meteor

I use the 3rd-party library meSpeak.js with Meteor. I haven't had problems with it before, but now when I try to load the Config data from public/mespeak_config.json, it gives me an error.

When I run "meSpeak.loadConfig("mespeak_config.json");" it gives me an error, no matter where I try it. In the console, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" (in Chrome), or "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data", in Firefox; when I navigate to the error, it is in the <!DOCTYPE html> of a generated HTML file.

Again, meSpeak.js has never given me this error before in this project (or any), and I don't understand why it does now.

When the page loads (and then some), I execute the ready() function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ready();
  }, 3000);
});
```

In the top of my ready() function, I include the meSpeak loading functions:

```
meSpeak.loadConfig("mespeak_config.json");
meSpeak.loadVoice("voices/en/en-us.json");
```

These don't load. They won't load when I execute them in the JavaScript console, either.

If I try to use meSpeak anyway, I get "No config-data loaded, deferring call." in the console.

Where's my issue?

Comment: Are you sure the files are actually present within your `public` directory? I would also suggest prefixing the path with `/` to make sure it's never treated as a relative path.

Comment: @apendua I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out why my dynamic route wasn't styled and your suggesting about prefixing with a forward slash just solved it. Good grief, now I can finally get some sleep.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby Good to hear that! :)

Comment: did you work this out? sounds like you just got some styles working but didnt solve the problem? if u did then probably should mark this as resolved. im having the same problem, trying to use meSpeak from within a node app using bower. it doesnt load the config, presumably because it cant find the lib/mespeak/... directories. im not sure where its trying to look from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@apendua said "Are you sure the files are actually present within your public directory? I would also suggest prefixing the path with / to make sure it's never treated as a relative path."
I solved my problem by prefixing the file paths with a "/". I don't understand why it worked earlier and stopped working later, but this fixed it.

Comment: i don't know why but in my case it works that way. Put all your javascript files to public directory and make sure to prefix the path with "/". This solution helps me solving few common css issues in meteor as well.